# Странное поведение os.system

Tags: python, cmd

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: каждый раз при вызове функции system из модуля os, выводится сообщение о том, что "Системе не удается найти указанный путь", при том что команда выполнилась успешно, да и вообще никаких путей не содержит. Почему так происходит?
Python 3.7.1, Windows 10 x64

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится (`Python 3.8 x64`, `Windows 10`), возвращает код `0`. Не могли бы Вы уточнить версию?

Comment: @nomnoms12, добавил информацию о версиях в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В результате небольшого исследования выяснилось, что такая ошибка возникла из-за установки программы ANSICON, в частности из-за того, что эта программа прописала запуск своих файлов в AutoRun при запуске консоли, а поскольку файлы отсутствовали, каждый раз при запуске выводилось это сообщение. Решается проблема с помощью очистки значения параметра `AutoRun` в реестре по адресу `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего хорошего это не предвещает.

Обычно, то есть у большинства людей, этой ошибки не будет. Просто выполнится команда, и вернёт значение ноль, которое отобразится в REPL. Поэтому, если вы искали решение, то ничего не нашли.

В исходном коде Питона, я функцию `system` не нашел, но [официальная документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) достаточно ясная: Python ничего специального с командой не делает, и просто вызывает стандартную функцию Си с тем же именем. Кстати, попробуйте выполнить `color 0B` на Си. Интересно, будет ли ошибка. Если да, то может это поможет найти причину.

Вот другой человек [жалуется на ту же проблему](https://narkive.com/7gEQRFJo.5) но решил он её... переустановкой Windows.

Comment: Попробовал на С++, при исполнении той же команды такой проблемы не возникает. Но насколько я понял, проблема и не в Питоне: при переназначении потока вывода sys.stdout на строковой буфер сообщение продолжает выводится, к тому же отображается только в cmd (в интерактивном сеансе IDLE, например, его нет).